# Using sscanf on buffer with new line characters: how to read all lines?

Tags: c, string, parsing, scanf

In C, how can I use sscanf over a buffer that contains new line character.

Example buffer:

```
buf = "Name: Sam\nID: 123\nLocation: 123\nDest: abc\0";
```

I want to do something like:

```
sscanf(buf, "%[^\n]s\n%[^\n]s\n%[^\n]s\n%[^\0]s", line1, line2, line3, line4);
```

but `sscanf` is only picking line1. Any ideas on how to make this work.

NOTE: I would really like to avoid looping over the buffer 4 times which can be a possible solution.

Comment: Lose the `s` in those specs, `"%[^\n]\n%[^\n]\n..."`. `sscanf` is looking for a string of anything-but-newline, then an `'s'` (which it doesn't find, then... you hopefully get the point).

Comment: Thanks that was the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to WhozCraig for the answer:

"Lose the s in those specs, "%[^\n]\n%[^\n]\n...". sscanf is looking for a string of anything-but-newline, then an 's' (which it doesn't find, then... you hopefully get the point)."